# How to get the first instance of a value partitioned by another column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table and I am trying to get the first person in the table with gender = 'M' and the first person with gender = 'F'

First person in this case = ORDER BY name in alphabetical order

```
name | gender | .......other data
A        M
B        M
C        F
D        F
E             
F        M
G        F
```

**How do I get a result table with the first instance of 'M' , 'F' without the null/empty column?**

Ideal result:

```
name | gender | ........other data
A       M
C       F
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: First: define `first` first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` function for that like this:

```
SELECT name,gender from (
    SELECT name,gender,
           row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY gender ORDER BY name ASC) as rnk
    FROM YourTable)
WHERE rnk = 1
```

You can add your other columns after the gender if you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name, gender
FROM your table
WHERE gender = "M"
ORDER BY NAME
Fetch first row only

Union all

SELECT name, gender
FROM your table
WHERE gender = "F"
ORDER BY NAME
Fetch first row only
```

Comment: I suggest you to use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` ;).

Answer (score 1):

One method in Postgres is to use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (gender) t.*
from t
order by gender, name;
```

This (conveniently) doesn't require listing all the genders in the query, can make use of an index on `(gender,name)`, and is often faster than `row_number()`.  Of course, the downside is that this is not standard, and only works in Postgres and Postgres-derived databases.

Comment: What does distinct on do?

Comment: @sagi . . . http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT.